# Does bash makes the terminal translates a newline (\n) to a carriage return (\r)?

Tags: terminal, newlines

I opened two terminals, and from the below terminal I executed `cat` to read from the above terminal:

[image]

In the above terminal I type `"Hello World<Enter>Bye"`, but looks like the above terminal sent the `Enter` key as a carriage return (`\r`).

So does `bash` changes the settings of the terminal to make it translates a newline (`\n`) to a carriage return (`\r`)?

Comment: hex it and see!!

Comment: `stty -a` should give a complete list of what the terminal settings are. In particular, the settings for `inlcr igncr icrnl` determine what the terminal does with CR-NL translation on input and the corresponding `o` flags tell what happens on output. Thomas DIckey's answer below explains how bash sets those flags in detail.

Comment: @Nick Does "on input" mean when the terminal send something to `bash` , and "on output" mean when `bash` send something to the terminal?

Comment: It means when the terminal sends something to the kernel. Similarly for output. Basically, user space tells the kernel how it wants terminal IO to be handled and the kernel obliges.

Comment: @Nick "on input" means when the terminal sends something to the kernel/tty device, and "on input" means when the `bash` sends something to the kerne/tty devicel?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Comment: @Nick I know how tty works, what I am asking is when I have an option like `icrnl`, what does this option means mean exactly? does it mean that when the terminal sends a `CR` to the tty device, the tty device will translate the `CR` to a `LF`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the stty(1) man page for the meaning of all the flags.

Answer (score 4):

Bash has changed the terminal to "raw" mode, which means typer characters are not processed in any way. The enter key produces a Carriage Return character (\r), not a Line Feed (\n), so no translation takes place.

Answer (score 3):

*raw* and *cooked* modes are descriptive terms.  `stty raw` uses different settings than bash.

Bash does terminal initialization in [prepare_terminal_settings](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rltty.c#n521) (an internal function of the readline library), setting the terminal mode to allow reading a single character at a time without echoing:

```
  tiop->c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
```

however, the carriage-return translation is reset in a [different part of the function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rltty.c#n548):

```
  /* Make sure we differentiate between CR and NL on input. */
  tiop->c_iflag &= ~(ICRNL | INLCR);
```

If you compare `prepare_terminal_settings` to the [coreutils `stty`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/stty.c#n1577), the latter does less (several points, but bash resets `INLCR` as well):

```
      else if (STREQ (info->name, "raw") || STREQ (info->name, "cooked"))
        {
          if ((info->name[0] == 'r' && reversed)
              || (info->name[0] == 'c' && !reversed))
            {
              /* Cooked mode. */
              mode->c_iflag |= BRKINT | IGNPAR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON;
              mode->c_oflag |= OPOST;
              mode->c_lflag |= ISIG | ICANON;
#if VMIN == VEOF
              mode->c_cc[VEOF] = CEOF;
#endif
#if VTIME == VEOL
              mode->c_cc[VEOL] = CEOL;
#endif
            }
          else
            {
              /* Raw mode. */
              mode->c_iflag = 0;
              mode->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
              mode->c_lflag &= ~(ISIG | ICANON
#ifdef XCASE
                                 | XCASE
#endif
                );
              mode->c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
              mode->c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
            }
        }
```

POSIX says of [`stty raw`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html):

> Enable (disable) raw input and output. Raw mode shall be equivalent to setting:

```
stty cs8 erase ^- kill ^- intr ^- \
    quit ^- eof ^- eol ^- -post -inpck
```

which interestingly enough (following the descriptions of `-post` and `-inpck`) does not address carriage return translation on input.

Since the terms *raw* and *cooked* (either POSIX or coreutils stty) do not correspond to what bash does, mentioning the POSIX termios features that correspond to what it actually does are the way to go: **`icrnl`** (*input carriage-return to newline translation*).

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. By default the terminal process (for example: `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, etc.) sends a `CR` to the tty device when you press `Enter`, but the tty device has a default setting to translate the `CR` to a `LF`, but now when `bash` runs it modifies this tty device setting to make it not translate the `CR` to a `LF`. Am I correct?

Comment: yes (though <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> normally is not configurable, so "By default" is redundant).

Comment: It's useful, though, because on virtual terminals what character the key causes to be transmitted _is_ configurable, via a keyboard map.